# how to use node_modules/@types/* and my own types together?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I use `typescript` with `webpack2` and `react`.

The `ProviderPlugin` of `webpack` provide some global variable.

And I use it in my `entry` file, like this:

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
console.log(__PROD__);
```

But `typescript` compiler give me an error:

`Error:(14, 13) TS2304:Cannot find name '__PROD__'.`

I create my own types file:

`./types/index.d.ts`:

```
declare const __PROD__: boolean;
```

my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2.3.4",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,

    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es2015",
      "DOM",
      "ScriptHost"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",

    "pretty": true,

    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"    
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "__test__"
  ]
}
```

You see, I already use `node_modules/@types` for `react` and other lib.

But how can I add my own type definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your configuration, it looks like you should just be able to add `./types/index.d.ts` to your `include`. If you've moved it to `./src/types/index.d.ts` as you said in your comment, do the same with that path.

## Explanation

Basically, all you want right now is to tell TypeScript about some global. You've already created a `types` folder with a `.d.ts` file that has all the information about the `__PROD__` global (i.e. `./types/index.d.ts`)

So you just need to have TypeScript read that file which it wasn't doing before. Simply add that file to your `include` list and everything should work.

Comment: I change my `baseUrl` to `./src` and move my `types` directory to `src`, it works. But, can you explain it ? Is that meanings, the content of `*.d.ts` file can be access for all `.ts` file? It that __global?__

Comment: OK. thanks. if I have many `*.d.ts` files,  I want to gather others `d.ts` into `index.d.ts` and just want to add `./types/index.d.ts` to my `include` list, How can I do that?

Comment: It's not clear from your existing setup and it depends on how the .d.ts files are written. [This StackOverflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796039/how-can-i-write-and-use-custom-declaration-files-that-dont-exist-on-definitelyt/44796040#44796040) might help, but otherwise I can't properly answer without more details.

Comment: Thanks! the answer is great!