# Why does retrofitting types onto soemthing untyped require a new npm package?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

Suppose that a package `foo` exists on `npm` which isn't typed, and I decide to locally write types for it in the style of `DefinitelyTyped`.

This situation was described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44796039/1412255) and the accepted answer tells you how to fake a "local npm package" to load these type declarations.

But why can't these types exist as a regular file (or even - a part of a file!) in my project? Does the typescript compiler give a special designation to packages -- in that packages can be used to declare types like this but files cannot?

Comment: Meta-question: why is the typescript such a hot mess? Perhaps this is inappropriate for SO a part of the question, so I've limited this to a comment. But if any technical discussions about if complexity in typescript is incidental or accidental exist, I'd love to read.

Comment: The short answer to your meta question is "because Javascript is a hot mess". The longer answer to your question is that just like every post-hoc system retrofitted on to something old with strong backwards compatibility and legacy constraints (see also C++) the chances of it being smooth and seamless are almost nil. They can't all be UTF-8. The answer to your *actual* question is that you can totally do that in TS, see the linked dupe below.

Comment: @JaredSmith thanks for pointing to that dupe. I guess maybe I'm struggling with typescript precisely because I'm new and because javascript is indeed complex, so I can also expect a type system to be. I'll reserve my judgement on typescript now till I have read the docs more thoroughly.

Comment: @JaredSmith I don't think that this question is quite a duplicate of the linked question since the question and answers don't talk about what DefinitelyTyped is and how it's used or why you can't use a "regular file," so to speak.

Comment: @ExplosionPills sure I guess? I thought it was close enough but it's a bit grey. We can both vote to reopen it if you want to write an answer but I wonder if such an answer would work better on one of the two linked questions.

Comment: @JaredSmith I was working on an answer that talks more about the purpose of `DefinitelyTyped` libraries, but it might not necessarily be appropriate for Stackoverflow. I think it is, but of course can't share it without the question being reopened.

Comment: @ExplosionPills well, I voted to reopen.