# When calling a JavaScript function from TypeScript, how do I override the inferred type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given the following **JavaScript** method:

```js
class SomeApi {
  async getData(signal = null) {
    const resp = await fetch(url, {signal});
    return resp.json()
  }
}
export default SomeApi()
```

When I call it with the **TypeScript** code below, I get a compile error, stating `Argument of type 'AbortSignal' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null | undefined'`

```js
import api from '...'

const abortController = new AbortController();
api.getData(abortController.signal).then(data => console.log);
```

It seems that TypeScript is incorrectly inferring the type of the JavaScript function's parameter. The correct type should be something like `AbortConroller | null`. I can eliminate the error with the common `getData(AbortController.signal as any)` hack, but is there a better way?

Assume that `SomeApi` is a library function and I cannot change the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the *code*, but you can extend or override the type definitions.  Using the `tsconfig.json` field `include`, pass a path to a folder where you will store your overrides (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44796040/135978) for more details).

Then you can have a `.d.ts` file like this:

```js
declare module "third/party/module" {
  class SomeApi {
    async getData(signal: AbortController | null): unknown;
  }
  const apiInstance: SomeApi;
  export default apiInstance;
}
```